# passing arrays as parameters to plsql procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need was playing around with sql developer and I have ran into a wall here...
I need to run a simple update query on a table and I want to pass in an array of Ids and update all the rows pointed by those Ids.

I have written the following stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROCEDURE(SAMPLE_ARRAY IN NUM_ARRAY)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE RETURNLIST_PICKLIST_MAPPING 
SET PICKLIST_ID = 1111111 
WHERE RETURNLIST_ID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(SAMPLE_ARRAY));
END SAMPLE_PROCEDURE;
```

`NUM_ARRAY` is a custom type defined as follows

```
create or replace 
TYPE NUM_ARRAY 
AS VARRAY(40) OF NUMBER(38, 0);
```

When I run the stored procedure in sql developer I want to input the value for SAMPLE_ARRAY. I have tried `(2222,1111,1234)` and `[2222,1111,1234]` and `{2222,1111,1234}` and each time I get "expression is of wrong type" error.

I desperate need help with this guys....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not show how did you assign values to your varray variable. But, I believe you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE 
V_T NUM_ARRAY;
BEGIN
V_T := NUM_ARRAY(1,2,3);
SAMPLE_PROCEDURE(V_T);
END;
/
```

In general, you can define a standalone VARRAY as follows:

```
CREATE Or REPLACE TYPE varray_type_name AS VARRAY(n) OF <element_type>;
```

Or, within PL/SQL block:

```
TYPE varray_type_name IS VARRAY(n) of <element_type>
```

Refer to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_arrays.htm) for more details

Comment: how to sense NUM_ARRAY through ADO.net?

Comment: @HorribleGuy Sorry, that's beyond my knowledge. I suggest you post another question and tag ADO